# Mysql Trigger to update columns in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to update a column in table2 when a column is updated in table1.

I have 2 table employees and company_details

This is my employee table

```
    emp_id  |  emp_name  |  location
       1    |     xxx    |  germany
       2    |     yyy    |  auckland
```

This is my company_details table

```
    id      |  emp_name  |    role
     1      |     xxx    |   software developer
     2      |     yyy    |   tester
```

When I try update column emp_name in `employee` table I would like update the field emp_name in `company_details` automatically. Can I write a query in which when one table column is updated the other table column also gets updated.

Comment: mysql and sql server are different beasts.Yes you can update multiple tables.

Comment: you can Use MERGE WITH UPDATE STATEMENTS

Comment: can you please give an example query? @Mihai

Comment: can you please give an example query? @Ganesh_Devlekar

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do it

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER emp_name_update
AFTER UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE company_details 
   SET emp_name = NEW.emp_name
 WHERE emp_name = OLD.emp_name;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0aff0/1)** demo

it's **a very bad** schema design. You should've used `emp_id` as a foreign key in `company_details` instead.

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  emp_id int not null primary key, 
  emp_name varchar(32), 
  location varchar(32)
);
CREATE TABLE company_details
(
  id int not null primary key,
  emp_id int, 
  role varchar(32),
  foreign key (emp_id) references employee (emp_id)
);
```

That way you don't need to update anything but rather `JOIN` both tables when you query it.

```sql
SELECT id, emp_name, role
  FROM company_details d JOIN employee e
    ON d.emp_id = e.emp_id;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/669fb/3)** demo